# how to generate codes for employee using mysql stored procedure?

Tags: mysql

I am new to mysql, i would like to know how to generate the employee codes like

Employee Name     Code
SANDEEP          SAN-001
SANJAY           SAN-002
MAHESH           MAH-001
SANTOSH          SAN-003
DEEPAK           DEE-001

using mysql stored procedure.

Quick answer is highly appreciated.

Comment: Beware of the Irish -- `O'Brian`.  My point is that you have underspecified the task, so I do not want to embark on the writing code for you.

Comment: in the above stored procedure, it is working properly, only the problem is that, if i generate five ids, like SAN-001, SAN-002, SAN-003, MAH-001, DEE-001  in this way. if i delete the id SAN-001, SAN-002 and again generate the id, it starts with SAN-001, SAN-002 and SAN-003. At 003 it gives duplication error. if there is SAN-003 then it should generate SAN-004 onwards taking the last id of the first three letters of employeename.

Comment: To avoid the deletion problem, you must keep a separate table saying that these are the max in use so far:  `('SAN', 3), ('MAH, 1), etc`

Answer (score 0):

A stored procedure would look something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS insertEmployee$$
CREATE PROCEDURE insertEmployee (IN NewName VARCHAR(6))
  BEGIN
    DECLARE CountStuff VARCHAR(5) DEFAULT '';
    SET CountStuff = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `employeecodes` WHERE LEFT(EmployeeName, 3) = LEFT(NewName, 3)) + 1;
    INSERT INTO employeecodes (`EmployeeName`, `Code`) VALUES (NewName, CONCAT(LEFT(NewName, 3),'-', LPAD(CONCAT(CountStuff), 3, '0')));
  END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

This will create the procedure insertEmployee which you can call like this:

```
CALL insertEmployee('SANDEEP');
```

This procedure will create a new employee with the code being the first three characters of the name and a count of the employees already existing in the database with that same name padded to 3 characters with a dash in between.

We use the

```
DELIMITER
```

function so that we can add a `;` to the sql statements within the procedure without stopping the procedure by accident.

Comment: @viraj no problem! if this answered your question, please don't forget to click the green checkmark :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that this is a Bad Idea.

You are including part of a Personal Data field (name) in the unique identifier for a person and that identifier will appear on every single record related to that person. 
In the World of G.D.P.R., i would say that this is questionable.

Even more importantly, what would you do if the person *changed* their name?
You *should* change their unique identifier to reflect their new name, which would involve changing each and every record related to that person ... and that could be a really, *really* big job in any sizeable database.

Seriously; as a unique key for an Employee, what's wrong with a sequentially-allocated number?